# I'm always online on Facebook even if I log off on all my devices

Tags: facebook

I'm always logged in with Facebook. I've close my Mac and my iPad, I'm still online.

I've checked the account activity from Facebook settings, and everything is fine, the only open connection is from my IP.

I've logged off from both iPad and Mac browser and I'm still online (my friends see me online).

I've tried several times to log out from browser and from iPad account, I'm always online. The only ways to go offline are:

- to change the chat settings about Availability in the browser
- to select: Go offline on iPad app (which is different from log out)

My questions are: why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: @Alex How-do-I-avoid-this-?

Comment: You say your friends see you online, so what happens when they try to send you a chat message?

Comment: Also, try deleting your cookies after you logout and see what happens.

Comment: I receive the message next time i login, as unread message

Comment: I've empited the cache, logout from the. rowser, and ive uninstalled the mobile app from my ipad. Im still online

Comment: It sounds a bit strange - have you tried turning ALL your devices COMPLETELY off?? If that doesn't work you need to contact Facebook.

Comment: This will be something you will need to take up with support.